# How To decode HTML Quotes in WebView

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have an Activity which is using a WebView and rendering html Data using WebView.LoadData();
it works fine for the most of html data,  but  if Html contains quoets like "
& # 6 0 ; p & # 6 2 ; & # 6 0;"
WebView can't decode that html Properly and shows html tags in the WebView.

Althogh i have tried this code :

```
    for(char c: rssFeed.getDescription().toCharArray()){

        switch (c) {
         case '#':  htmlBuffer.append("%23"); break;
         case '%':  htmlBuffer.append("%25"); break;
         case '\'': htmlBuffer.append("%27"); break;
         case '?':  htmlBuffer.append("%3f"); break;     
         case '&':  htmlBuffer.append("%26"); break;
         case ':':  htmlBuffer.append("%3A"); break;
         case ';':  htmlBuffer.append("%3B")  ;break;
         case '/': htmlBuffer.append("%2F"); break;


         default:
           htmlBuffer.append(c);
           break;
        }
    }
```

but doesn't help.

Comment: In the `WebView.loadData` are you passing any encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding everything using Base64. The  following should work:

```
String content  = "html content";  // the html data
String base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(data.getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
webView.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
```